# Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working using codeigniter but keep getting the error in the title of this question. Here is my code to include the js files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have checked to see what version of JQuery I am actually running and it is 2.1.4. Has anyone else come across this problem or even better a solution?

Comment: Your first line loads jquery 1.7 ... http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js

Comment: Bollocks. That would probably be it.